# Re-formatting JSON repsonse with scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I output the scraped data in json format. Default scrapy exporter outputs list of dict in json format. Item type looks like:

```
[{"Product Name":"Product1", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"20.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product2", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"21.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product3", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"22.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product4", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"23.5", "Currency":"USD"}, ...]
```

But I want to export the data in a specific format like so - So I will set the Shop Name, Location, Contact manually in a var. Then will need to get the data which I crawled and paste it in an array in the Products key - value.

```
{
"Shop Name":"Shop 1",
"Location":"XXXXXXXXX",
"Contact":"XXXX-XXXXX",
"Products":
[{"Product Name":"Product1", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"20.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product2", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"21.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product3", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"22.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product4", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"23.5", "Currency":"USD"}, ...]
}
```

The below is my code how I'm getting the crawled data.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for products in response.css('div.single_product'):
            yield {
                'name': products.css('h4.product_name::text').get(),
                'price': products.css('span.current_price::text').get(),
                'code': products.css('div.single_product').attrib['data-itemcode'],
                'url' : urljoin("https://xxxx", products.css('a.image-popup-no-margins').attrib['data-image'] )
            }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I'm having difficulty formatting a json file as above. Getting the data from scrapy and presenting as part of a json document.

Answer (score 0):

Format a dict and yield it (instead of yielding each item separately), example:

```py
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['scrapingclub.com']
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': {
            'items.json': {
                'format': 'json',
                'encoding': 'utf8',
                'indent': 4,
            }
        }
    }

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        products = list()
        for product in response.xpath('//div[@class="card"]'):
            products.append(
                {'title': product.xpath('.//h4/a/text()').get(default=''),
                 'price': product.xpath('.//h5//text()').get(default='')}
            )

        item = dict()
        item['URL'] = response.url
        item['Products'] = products
        yield item

        next_page = response.xpath('//ul[@class="pagination"]//li[last()]/a/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(url=next_page)
```